# Does a PC need pure sine wave? Need to test using 1000W, 120VAC 60HZ input, 240VAC 50HZ output

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, mains, computers

I need an OTS (Off The Shelf) solution to test PCs before they ship to Europe and beyond. I need to provide up to 1000W of 240vDC 50Hz power from a 120vAC 60Hz outlet, because I want to make sure the (not Brand X, but from quality manufacturers) off-the-shelf PC power supplies which are specified to work with both 120vAC@50Hz and 240vAC@50Hz we build into the PCs behave OK with EU current.

Specific power supplies which come back with customer complaints of noise or other bad behavior will be tested. The power supplies in question will be tested outside of a PC with an artificial load, and then tested in a open chassis before going into a PC chassis of the type used by the customer.

Why? We've gotten complaints of power supply buzzing and crackling noise from our customers which we want to resolve expeditiously.

What are your thoughts about a 120VAC to 12VDC converter wired to a 12VDC to 240VAC power supply, both rated to handle 1000W or more? [image: Very rough sketch]

Does a PC need a pure sine wave, or is a 'modified' sine wave adequate?

Comment: Why do you ask about both AC-DC and sine wave? What your "PC" is expecting as a power source?

Comment: Why? Don't you trust your vendors? You should be asking **them** what kind of power they expect. In any case, there are plenty of COTS (**Commercial** Off-The-Shelf) power converters out there for just this kind of testing. If you try to go cheap on this, how far can you trust your own test results?

Comment: _Dave Tweed_, I have customer complaints on hand, which is why I look to test. When I look for OTS 1000W power converters, I don't find any which handle the change in frequency. Zip, zero, none, at either electrical supply houses or big-name-web-sellers-named-after-rivers. Also, I am not asking for brands, I am not asking for vendors. I have described my need, and have specific questions regarding the need for a pure sine wave vs 'modified' sine wave, & if a 120vAC 60Hz to 12vDC power supply can connect to a 240vAC 50Hz converter to emulate what my EU customer gets out of their wall.

Comment: And, I used COTS reflexively, because of government procurement background, where we would use COTS to mean no $5,000 toilet seats.

Comment: Look for frequency converters. There are rotating motor generator sets that would provide a really pure sine wave. There are also various static solutions of varying power quality.. The advantage of using something crude would be it might be good to demonstrate the product works fine with "dirty" power. However you may want to figure out what sort of input voltage distortion is problematic.

Comment: Does a PC supply *need* a pure sine wave supply? No, it's just rectified and turned back into DC for a flyback type supply anyway, but the bigger PSUs have power factor correction that will attempt to match the current drawn to be in phase with the supply voltage, so they may behave unpredictably with a poor incoming waveform and be noisy anyway - even if they work fine on a clean sine supply. I've always used rotary converters for testing in these situations.

Comment: In short, yes it should be a sine wave as surge currents from dv/dt not only create excessive currents , they excite piezo electric effects on ceramics. Unless rated for such inputs with active PFC circuits and CM Pi filters designed to withstand this!  Get a VFD to Test them over the range you want with a sine wave. Along with your dirty Inverter.

Comment: Bit dangerous approach, but you are not doing type testing of a product with this method, only some kind of "smoke test" to minimize DOA at customer site?

Comment: I have skinned this the other way before now (making a 60Hz tonewheel organ work in europe) by using a butch audio power amplifier (I used an old Crown MA5000VZ) and a signal generator. To get 240V you would probably need to stick the output thru a step up transformer, but it is all doable.

Comment: _winny_, this is for testing specific power supplies which come back with customer complaints of noise or other bad behavior. The power supplies in question will be tested outside of a PC with an artificial load, and then tested in a open chassis before going into a PC chassis.

Comment: _Eugene Sh_, I ask about both AC-DC and sine wave because I need to generate wall socket power such as is used in the EU and Asia, and my lab only has US 60Hz 120vAC power. There are many devices which generate 50Hz 220vAC-240vAC; some providing 'modified' sine wave, less with unqualified true sine wave current.  These "PC" (personal computers) are expecting EU-standard mains current as a power source.